# Product Page => Error Processing Request: Invalid Method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Simple::displayProductStockStatus(Array)

Tags: magento, runtime-error

I'm working on a Magento version 1.9.0.1

I get this error when looking at any product page:

There has been an error processing your request

```html
Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Simple::displayProductStockStatus(Array
(
)
)

Trace:
#0 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml(27): Varien_Object->__call('displayProductS...', Array)
#1 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml(27): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Simple->displayProductStockStatus()
#2 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/homepages/32/d...')
#3 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/de...')
#4 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product_type_av...', true)
#8 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(69): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('product_type_av...')
#9 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/homepages/32/d...')
#10 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/de...')
#11 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#12 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#14 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#15 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#17 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#18 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/homepages/32/d...')
#19 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/de...')
#20 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#21 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#24 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#25 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#26 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(75): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#27 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction()
#28 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
#29 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#30 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#31 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#32 /homepages/32/d272998686/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/BirrArtesana/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#33 {main}
```

Error log record number: 641823913

I've tried to sold it creating this "tmp" directory an such, but no success.

:(

Any help?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This may happen due to an update of Magento engine.
If you've updated Magento prior the issue appeared, try to copy the file from, for example, RWD theme (or "default" theme):

/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml

/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml

And place it into:

/app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/view/type